# Facet for counting index and type hits in elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, faceted-search

I'm using the query below to find the word "developer" in a blog index...

```
http://localhost:9200/blog/_search
{ 
   "query": {
     "query_string": {
        "query": "developer"
      }
    }
}
```

The query returns 3 hits on `user` and 1 hit on `post` types, and I want a facet to reflect those hits to display something like...

**Search Results...**
Blogs Posts (1)
Users (3)

...but I'm not sure how to combine a facet with a query to count such hits since most examples I found count field hits; I tried using `_index` to return index hits, but could not get it to work; is there something similar for types, like `_type`, to count document type hits within an index?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, apparently there is a `_type` field for facets, based on this...

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/enabled-quot-index-quot-does-not-allow-me-to-get-facet-values-td1056215.html

**Query**

```
http://localhost:9200/blog/_search

    {
      "size" : 0,
      "query" : {   
         "query_string" : {
            "query" : "developer"}
       },
      "facets" : {
        "type" : {
          "terms" : { "field" : "_type"}
        }
      }
    }
```

**Response**

```
{
  ...
  "facets": {
    "type": {
      "_type": "terms",
      "missing": 0,
      "total": 4,
      "other": 0,
      "terms": [
        {
          "term": "user",
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "term": "post",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```